# Sort dataframe with multi index

Tags: python, pandas

A simple example, let's say I have this DataFrame:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [1, 2, 5, 'User 1', 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 'User 2', 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 'User 3', 5],
    [3, 2, 4, 'User 4', 7],
    [3, 2, 3, 'User 5', 2],
    [3, 1, 6, 'User 6', 5],
    [2, 2, 6, 'User 7', 1],
    [2, 2, 5, 'User 8', 4],
    [2, 2, 3, 'User 9', 8],
]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

and below that code:

```
raw.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], inplace=True)
raw.sort_index()
raw.head(9)
```

The output looks like that:

[image: The output of the Dataframe]

Instead of sorting it first by `a`, then by `b`, then by `c`. ( the whole row )
How could it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `inplace=True` parameter [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
raw.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Or assign output back:

```
raw = raw.sort_index()

print (raw)
            d  e
a b c           
1 2 2  User 3  5
    3  User 2  3
    5  User 1  5
2 2 3  User 9  8
    5  User 8  4
    6  User 7  1
3 1 6  User 6  5
  2 3  User 5  2
    4  User 4  7
```